# Implementing Perl's pack function in .NET

Tags: c#, perl

I need some help with the following line in perl:

```
pack "NN", $b, $a;
```

I can't really understand how to convert that to C#. where a & b are both int

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand [what the pack statement does](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)? Have to tried to find a matching C# method? If yes, where are you stuck?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In .NET the result would not be a string, but a byte array. A string is composed of 16-bit `char` values, so that is not convenient for representing 8-bit data.

Use a method like this to get the "network" representation of an integer:

```
public static byte[] ToNetwork(int value) {
  byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
  if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) {
    Array.Reverse(data);
  }
  return data;
}
```

Write the byte arrays to a memory stream:

```
int a = 1;
int b = 42;
byte[] result;

using (MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream()) {
  m.Write(ToNetwork(a), 0, 4);
  m.Write(ToNetwork(b), 0, 4);
  result = m.ToArray();
}
```

Now you have an array with eight bytes; each integer in big endian format.

Answer (score 0):

Mono provides a nice Pack/Unpack API, [DataConverter](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert#Obtaining_Mono.DataConvert) (inspired after the Perl pack and unpack functions). Source code is available in git [repro](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/Mono/DataConverter.cs) (BSD License)

```
{
    byte [] data = DataConverter.Pack("^II", 12345678, 87654321);
    var result = DataConverter.Unpack("^II", data, 0);
    Console.Write ("{0}, {1}\n", result[0], result[1]);
}
```